# Make a custom Pick List field required when certain condition is fulfilled

Tags: picklist, custom-field, validation-rule, required-field

Could you guys please help me make a validation rule if when our "Invoice_Paid_Date__c" custom field is not blank then require "Send_Upsale_Email__c" to be filled out (Its a yes/no picklist). I'm new to understanding validation rules so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. if you're new to validation rules, [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules) is your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Validation rule as follows in that object,

**Validation Description:**
This below validation rule checks, Invoice Paid date is not blank and Send Upsale Email is blank (on that particular time). If both are Yes, It's escalate a validation error (Validation error can be able to placed on both **Top of the page** or any field like **Send Upsale Email** positions.)

```
NOT(ISBLANK( Invoice_Paid_Date__c )) && (ISBLANK(TEXT(Send_Upsale_Email__c)))
```

Please let me know if it's helps.